# What is this light passenger prop airplane which crash landed in East Kalimantan, Borneo in 1983?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Plane crash landed in Borneo jungle in 1983.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

That registration looks like `PK-DCR` to me. It's a little bit blurry, but especially if you zoom in, it's fairly readable.

A quick web search for that registration and "airplane" brings me Wikipedia's page on [Deraya Air Taxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deraya_Air_Taxi#Accidents_and_Incidents), which indicates that

> On November 1982, Indonesian Aerospace 212-100 PK-DCR of Deraya Air Taxi and PT Pupuk Kaltim was damaged when it approaching Bontang. No fatalities in this accident.

The 212-100 brings us to the [CASA C-212 Aviocar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CASA_C-212_Aviocar#Variants).

Looking at the pictures on Wikipedia, it's pretty close, so that's probably it. Note the pretty distinctive tail section, and the relative dimensions:

[image]
<sup>([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CASA_212_N160FB_Northwest_Airlink.jpg); photo by RuthAS, published under CC-BY-3.0)</sup>

[image]
<sup>([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lloyd_Aviation_CASA_212_PER_Wheatley.jpg); photo by John Wheatley, published under under GFDL-1.2)</sup>

Comment: Believe these were assembled locally in Indonesia by IPTN.

Comment: Thanks for walking through your search process instead of just providing an answer. If you teach a man to fish...

Comment: @FreeMan That was my idea as well. Knowing where to start, answering the question itself was pretty trivial, but hopefully showing how to approach (no pun intended) questions like this will help at least some other people as well, who are curious about aircraft in other pictures. The real key here was that the registration was visible, so I didn't have to do much guessing.

Answer (score 5):

The aircraft was a CASA 212 registered PK-DCR which crashed on November 8th 1982, near Bontang, East Kalimantan

[Bureau of Aircraft Accidents](https://www.baaa-acro.com/zone/east-kalimantan)

[image]